# How to parse deeper JSON nodes inside of DataStore Ext.define()

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, model-view-controller, extjs4

I'm trying to implement a web-based Desktop application for administration purpose of my website. When I tried to rewrite the BogusMenuModule and BogusModule which are examples of ExtJS, I was unable to get deeper nodes of JSON by using     `myDataStore.load({callback:function(){...}})`     inside of     `Ext.define('MyDesktop.BasicWindowModule', {...})`    . I'm only able to get the first layer's ID.

If     `myDataStore(...)`     is outside of     `Ext.define(...)`     it works, but the problem is that it's unable to set parameters to 'win' which is an inside variable of     `Ext.define(...)`    .

Why I'd like to modify them is that I wanna implement a base-class module in order to pass taskbar ID to it and create a new taskbar instead of creating a new js file for my taskbar every time.

What I mean by deeper nodes is that if there's only one layer in JSON, it worked fine. But it doesn't work if the JSON looks like:

```
{
"BasicWindows": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "window": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "ControlPanel",
            "hasButton": false,
            "configs": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "title": "ControlPanel",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 480
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "window": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Customers",
            "hasButton": true,
            "configs": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "Customers",
                    "width": 400,
                    "height": 300,
                    "button": [
                        {
                            "text": "Submit"
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "Cancel"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "window": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Reports",
            "hasButton": false,
            "configs": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "Reports",
                    "width": 600,
                    "height": 400
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

And my modified BogusModule looks like:

```
 Ext.require([
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.window.Window'
]);
Ext.define('BasicWindow',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
           {name: 'id', type:'int'}
       ],
    hasMany : {model : 'myWindow', name : 'window'}
});

Ext.define('myWindow',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
           {name: 'id', type:'int'},
           {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
           {name: 'hasButton', type: 'boolean'}
       ],
    hasMany : {model : 'myConfigs', name : 'configs'},   
    belongsTo: 'BasicWindow'
});

Ext.define('myConfigs', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
           {name: 'id', type:'int'},
           {name: 'title', type: 'string'},
           {name: 'width', type: 'int'},
           {name: 'height', type: 'int'}
       ],
    hasMany : {model : 'myButton', name : 'button'},
    belongsTo: 'myWindow'    
});

Ext.define('myButton',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
           {name: 'text', type:'string'}
       ],
    belongsTo: 'myConfigs'        
});

var myDataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'BasicWindow',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'js/extjs/src/desktop/json/BasicWinConfig.json',
            reader:{ 
                type:'json',
                root: 'BasicWindows'
            }
        }
});

var windowIndex = 0;
//function GetWindowName
Ext.define('MyDesktop.BasicWindowModule', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.desktop.Module',

    init : function(){
        this.launcher = {
            //text: 'Auto Search',
            iconCls:'bogus',
            handler : this.createWindow,
            scope: this,
            windowId:windowIndex
        };
    },

    createWindow : function(src){
        var desktop = this.app.getDesktop();
        var win = desktop.getWindow('BasicWindow');
        var form = new Ext.form.Panel({
                border: false,
                fieldDefaults: {
                    labelWidth: 60
                }
            });

        if(!win){
            win = desktop.createWindow({
                        autoShow: true,
                        id: 'BasicWindow',
                        //title: 'Auto Search',
                        //width: 240,
                        //height:200,
                        //minWidth: 240,
                        //minHeight: 200,
                        layout: 'fit',
                        plain: true,
                        items: form
                });

            myDataStore.load({callback:function(){
                alert('This is inside load callback');
                myDataStore.each(function(rec) {
                    var window = rec.get('window');
                    alert(window.getId());
                    rec.each(function(conf){
                        alert(conf.getId());
                        win.add({ 
                                title: config.get('title'),
                                width: config.get('width'),
                                height: config.get('height')
                        });
                    });

                });
            }});
        }
        win.show();
        return win;
    }

});
```

Any comment or answer would be appreciated.

Comment: If the very last few lines starting from myDataStore.load is outside of Ext.define(), nodes are able to be gotten.

Comment: The problem is if myDataStore is outside, win is unable to be set configs like title, width, and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Add the line outside of Ext.define

```
var me = this;
```

and then

```
me.myDataStore.load(...);
```

Another question comes out. How can I load myDataStore if I move Models and DataStore definition to another .js file?

Any suggestion?

```
Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myDataStore');
```

This function didn't work for ExtJS4 in my case.

Comment: There's no way to add store like this except following ExtJS MVC framework rules. I'm starting to join desktop and MVC examples together.